# Run all tests in package using gradle command

Tags: android, gradle, automated-tests, android-gradle-plugin, junit4

To run tests in package according to docs we should use

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e package com.android.foo.bar com.android.foo/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

So for the gradle command it will be:

```
./gradlew connectedCheck -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.package=com.android.foo.bar
```

However, in my case, runner just run every android tests from all android test packages. When I use `class` instead `package`, then run `testInstrumentationRunnerArguments` will run single class.

Any idea what I am possibly doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!